# Algorithm to find cycles in a directed graph with some constraints

Tags: graph, graph-theory, cycle

I have a graph with the given constraints:
1. The graph is directed
2. At most 2 edges emerge from a vertex
3. At most 2 edges lead into a vertex

In this graph, I want to find cycles, so that:
a) each vertex is only a part of one cycle
b) every vertex is part of some cycle

I've spent some time on this problem already, but as easy as it sounds, 
It doesn't seem so trivial.

An extension of the question is as follows:
Each edge additionally has a span, two real numbers,
and a 'pivot' must be selected,
so that all edges that end up in the cycles 
can 'fit' pivot into their span range.
I.e. for pivot 100 one can use edge [20, 100], because 100 is in [20, 120]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is called finding a [vertex-disjoint cycle cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cycle_cover). It can be found in polynomial time as described in [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/8570/8165)

Your extended question is not clear to me. Are you given the pivot? Then you'd simply remove the non-fitting edges. Do you have to chose one? With luck you may be able to modify the perfect matching search to satisfy this. But careful, such additional conditions easily make the difference between a polynomial and NP-hard problem.